# How do remote dependency managers for tools like grapes/maven/ivy manage to utilize the same underlying repositories ....?

Tags: java, maven, ant, ivy

It seems as though ivy , maven, grapes , and other dependency managers link to the same integrated repositories.

1) What do these different dependency managers have in common in terms of the way that 
resources are checked and downloaded ?

2) When i have a package name in an ivy or maven file -- how can I find the curators of that package ?  Where are these remote java resources unified and managed ?

I'm not asking for the "development lifecycle" scope of information here, but rather, I want to know specifically how grapes/maven/ivy are capable of playing nicely together, i.e. , is what is the standard for resolving remote java repositories ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the [Maven Central repository](http://search.maven.org/) that ties together these tools. Tools like ivy can be configured to use their own repository format, but default to using the public Maven repository for downloads.

Maven Central is maintained by Sonatype, the creators of both [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/) and the [Nexus repository manager](http://nexus.sonatype.org/). It is estimated that it will soon host 90% of Java's open source libraries.

Maven central can be searched using the following URL:

- http://search.maven.org

And the following guide gives information on how one can upload artifacts:

- http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-central-repository-upload.html

Information on the ownership of modules is normally available from the module's POM file. Artifacts are also signed, using PGP, to prove ownership.

In conclusion, while Maven may one of several dependency management clients, it has certainly established itself as the de-facto standard for server-side repository management.